# What term describes "a loss of immersion" while reading?

Tags: phrase-requests

If a book is good, readers can easily imagine the story and forget they are reading. If they encounter a problem, perhaps a spelling error or something unbelievable within the universe of the story, the reader suddenly loses this immersion.

- Is there a formal term which means "something which causes a loss of immersion"?
- Is there a technical or more formal phrase meaning "to lose immersion"?

Comment: Distracted, Brought back to reality,

Comment: In video game design this is commonly referred to as "breaking immersion".

Comment: I can't find the reference, but I think I've seen this called *resurfacing*. One definition of [*resurface* is:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/resurface) To come to the surface again; reappear. Maybe someone else can cite a reference.

Comment: I would normally say the event "broke their concentration".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sense of immersion is closely related to what Coleridge described with the phrase "suspension of disbelief" or "willing suspension of disbelief". We know that the events are not true (or maybe, as in the case of science fiction, fantasy or magical realism, even possible), but we suspend the effect of this knowledge and allow ourselves to react as if they were true.

Something which undoes this effect is often referred to as "breaking suspension of disbelief".

More generally, we may just refer to the reader as being *distracted*, or simply "a break in audience immersion" particularly with the minor details: If I've been reading a story which for 500 pages has brought me through the machinations of an 18th-Century matriarch set upon finding her daughters good marriages and suddenly a UFO lands in her mansion's grounds, I'm likely to find that brings a total break in suspension of disbelief. If I hit upon a clumsy sentence that is hard to parse that will likely distract me from the story in a different way to suspension of disbelief (it could after all happen with a true story I do believe), though it would certainly not help that suspension.

A deliberate attempt to trigger distraction and force the audience to consider the difference between the fiction and reality is often called *alienation*, *distancing effect*, *estrangement* or the German loan-word *verfrumdungseffekt*. It might be called *Brechtian alienation* to distinguish it from other uses of that word.

*Estrangement* can also refer to the continuing knowledge that e.g. a sci-fi story cannot be literally true, even as it happens in tandem with suspension of disbelief.

Comment: Some of these terms could use Wikipedia or dictionary links. Interesting stuff.

Comment: @coleopterist A search on Coleridge and even more so on the phrase "suspension of disbelief" will provide much on the first bit, and on Bertolt Brecht for the second bit. Just be wary of anything that brings you to tvtropes.org, as that site is even more of a time-sink than stack exchange - it's safe enough until you start opening multiple tabs.

Answer (score 1):

### Sudden Loss of Suspension of Disbelief – SLSD

I have had SLSD since my 40s. First I lost interest in fiction books, then
gradually for movies. I can go to the cinema to support my company and have
no trouble watching a movie for the sake of a date, but would never watch
it on my own or on TV. If it’s fiction I find it boring and predictable, so
instead of following the plot I wonder why the author or director chose
that approach, and I start having social concerns of why people react or
think predictably, man-meets-woman, drama, danger, man-saves-woman,
man-kills-bad-guys, happy ending, etc. It doesn’t matter if the formulas
differ because there’s always a pattern or a *déjà-vu* structure aimed at
attracting viewers and attention.

Sometimes I make an effort, but as soon as the movie starts I fast-forward
to the end and just watch the final scene. Seen it. Move on. In my early
years with SLSD this happened just with Hollywood movies; I despised
American movies as a trend of mediocrity, regarded its movies childish
product of adults with teenage minds. On the other hand European or
international movies were different: I used to be able to watch them with
no problems with my suspension of disbelief.  But as globalization has
influenced everybody, this original approach from many cultures was lost so
that nowadays virtually everybody follows the Hollywood formula.

Today I can only watch documentaries (and even so just a few good ones),
read real news, history books, and texts about the universe and life; those
still fascinate me. I retain an attitude of arrogance uninterested by
anything imagined by others, by anything that comes from someone else’s
mind which is aimed at selling or making a profit.

Comment: Hello Luis, and welcome to our site! The condition you speak of is personally familiar to me. I hope you will not mind that I've taken the liberty to lightly edit your fascinating post to make its formatting work better here (like by placing blank lines between paragraphs and such) and to improve the flow of the text in a few places by altering punctuation or adding a small word here or there. If I've anywhere altered the text to say something you did not mean, then please by all means re-edit it yourself to fix this. You may also be interested in our sites for [spanish.se] or [portuguese.se].